# Remove parentage form child window

Tags: javascript, window, parent-child

I am dealing with an old developer's site and code.

There is a GLOBAL print function the guy wrote that basically senses for any new window that opens (from any method) and "href.match"es the domain name... the script then applies a print stylesheet if need be and fires window.print.

This is all done from a global script that is on every page and houses some other functions.

I am tired of writing cases for each page added that I want to escape this function.  Also if I do write a NOT clause for the certain page, any subsequent page opened within the domain in the child window will then receive that print function.

Is there a way to "bust" the inheritance in this new window?  Basically to make this window NOT the child of the parent that spawned it?

```
    addEvent(window, 'load', function () {
    var printBtn = document.getElementById('print-page');
    if (window.opener && window.opener.location.href.match('domainnamehere')) {
        var printCSS = document.createElement('link');
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        printCSS.href = 'css/print.css'
        printCSS.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        printCSS.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(printCSS);

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i].href="";
            a[i].onclick = function () { return false; };
            a[i].style.cursor = "default";
        }

        window.print();
    } else if (printBtn){
        printBtn.onclick = function () {
            var printWindow = window.open(window.location, 'printwindow', 'resizable,width=800,height=800,scrollbars');

            return false;
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `opener` property is what gives access to the child window, so if you want to disconnect it all you have to do is set it to null.  When doing this, I always copy it to another property before nullifying in case you need it for other reasons...

```
if(bustInheritance) {
  window.oldOpener = window.opener;
  window.opener = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but might do the trick:

```
var win_onload = window.onload;
// replace it with a function that does nothing
window.onload = function () { };

... open your window ...

// put the event handler back
wndow.onload = win_onload;
```

Comment: By 5 seconds... ninjas are among us.