# window.open - how to breaking the relationship between child and parent?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript condition which checks whether the given page is opened within a child window. If it validates to true, then I would want it to break the parent-child relationship as I don't want my page to opened in a child window. The condition I used is:

```
if (window.opener!= null && !window.opener.closed)
{
/* break relationship code */
}
```

Or even better, make the child window the parent window. Is it possible?

Comment: You can just change the `window.opener` directly I believe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove parentage form child window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961968/remove-parentage-form-child-window)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.opener = null;
```

This does the job. However, this only means that the child will not be able to access the parent window (if you didn't make a copy of `window.opener`). The parent window can still access the child window.

Comment: I want it the other way round. The parent window shouldn't have access to the child window. Here's what I did. I am trying to open my page as a child and redirect it to a different page after 30 seconds via JavaScript variable in the parent page. So the script should detect that the page was indeed opened as a child and hence the redirection should fail, that is the parent window should lose access to child window.

Comment: @bAdbOy - You can't really remove the access to the child window. The most you can do is to set the reference variable of the child window to undefined, but you can still regain the connection with `window.open`.

Comment: So you mean to say that there's no way to prevent a page from being opened in a child window?

Comment: @bAdbOy - As far as I know every window opened by your script can be accessed (as long as both are in the same domain) until it is closed. You might want to try creating a `<a>` and triggering it with a `click` event though.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 would this not be: `window.opener = null;` (e.g. not a string)?

Comment: @scunliffe I have no idea why I quoted it.